# how to find the integral of a matrix exponential in python

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, integration, exponential

I have a matrix of the form, say `e^(Ax)` where `A` is a square matrix. How can I integrate it from a given value `a` to another value `b`so that the output is a corresponding array?

Comment: what are `a` and `b` in this case?

Comment: I suspect you want to use `scipy` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html

Answer (score 2):

Provided A has the right properties, you could transform it to the diagonal form A0 by calculating its eigenvectors and eigenvalues. In the diagonal form, the solution is `sol = [exp(A0*b) - exp(A0*a)] * inv(A0)`, where `A0` is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues and `inv(A0)` just contains the inverse of the eigenvalues in its diagonal. Finally, you transform back the solution by multiplying it with the transpose of the eigenvalues from the left and the eigenvalues from the right: `transpose(eigvecs) * sol * eigvecs`.

Comment: Thank you very much Aradi for the good approach to the problem and tcaswell for the reference. But then, how can I implement this in python for instance scipy.integrate.quad or something similar? I know how to do that for a single function, not a matrix. Is forming a loop the only solution? Thanks again. oh, a and b are scalars, limits of integration for x to run through.